# How to enable CORS for all get functions in the Angular project?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How to enable CORS for all get functions of the rxjs libarary in the all scope of the Angular project?
In other words, Access-Control-Allow-Origin should be any (*).

Comment: cors issue will be handle from backend.

Comment: from frontEnd you can send header like this but cors will handle from backend. 
headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
  }